# Passing Kerberos Credentials in PDFKIT python pdf generator tool

Tags: python, pdf-generation, kerberos, python-pdfkit

I have a URL which requires Kerberos Credentials (single sign on) for Authentication. I need to generate PDF of this URL response webpage. but when i am trying using pdfkit  i am getting authentication error. Can anyone please provide the necessary headers need to be set.

```html
import pdfkit

options = {
    'custom-header':  [('WWW-Authenticate:', 'negotiate')]
}


pdfkit.from_url(
    'URL-link',
    'shaurya.pdf', options=options)
```